# How to build boost::locale for android

Tags: android, c++, boost, boost-locale

I have a project which has boost 1.64 which works on android. now, I need enable `boost::locale` library which depends on `ICU` / `ICONV` libs. 
I download https://github.com/pelya/libiconv-libicu-android, and compiled it succeefully. Then I add list

```
(APPEND BOOST_FLAGS  boost.locale.icu=on -sICU_PATH=MY_PATH/libiconv-libicu-android-master/armeabi-v7a -sICONV_PATH=MY_PATH/libiconv-libicu-android-master/armeabi-v7a)
```

to my cmake file. But unfortunately, the boost log still tells me:

```
Performing configuration checks

- 32-bit                   : no  (cached)
- 64-bit                   : yes (cached)
- arm                      : yes (cached)
```

Building the Boost C++ Libraries.

```
- symlinks supported       : yes (cached)
- zlib                     : yes (cached)
- iconv (libc)             : no  (cached)
- iconv (separate)         : no  (cached)
- icu                      : no  (cached)
- icu (lib64)              : no  (cached)
- Boost.Locale needs either iconv or ICU library to be built.
- Boost.Locale needs either iconv or ICU library to be built.
- Boost.Locale needs either iconv or ICU library to be built.
- Boost.Locale needs either iconv or ICU library to be built.
- Boost.Locale needs either iconv or ICU library to be built.
- Boost.Locale needs either iconv or ICU library to be built.
- has_icu builds           : no  (cached)
```

from the `boost::locale` official document, I find that seems ICU libraries are shared libraries, but libiconv-libicu-android only gives static libs. Is it matters?

hope anyone can help, thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried compile iconv on 32bit android and works. but 64bit still failed, can any one gives a hit

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I made it worked, by using libicon-libicu-android[https://github.com/pelya/libiconv-libicu-android]. To be make sure that the compiler to compile your project and libiconv-libicu are compatible. I encounter an issue which is caused by different edition android ndk. seems libicon-libicu use ndk-15 & llvm. but our project use ndk 10. I encounter a link error when ld trying to link libiconv. so please make sure your project use the compatible ndk with libiconv-libicu. if not, try to modify the setCrossEnvironment-XXX.sh file to make it compatible. Also, boost has libiconv as backend is enough. so the part of building icu lib in the sh can be ignored.
when the libiconv.so or libiconv.a is ready, you set boost compile variable: -sICONV_PATH=/your_iconv_path. if every thing goes fine you can get the boost::locale lib.

BTW, you can debug boost error from config.log and boost_(shared/static).log. if boost_(shared/static).log has
    - symlinks supported       : yes
    - zlib                     : yes
    - iconv (libc)             : no
    - iconv (separate)         : yes
    - has_icu builds           : no
you should compile the boost::locale successfully. If all iconv option shows "no", you should read config.log to find the reason if you have assigned libiconv path. Boost::locale build system seems will try to build a very simple iconv demo to verify the env. if that can't be built completely, Boost will present the error in config.log. Trying to figure out why it doesn't work, always helpful.

Hope you will build android boost::locale smoothly.